# Javascript: Find key and its value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that is returned in different ways, but always has `key`. How can I get it?

E.g.

```
"Records": {
    "key": "112"
}
```

Or

```
"Records": { 
    "test": {
        "key": "512"
    }
}
```

Or even in array:

```
"Records": { 
    "test": {
        "test2": [
            {
                "key": "334"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Tried several options, but still can't figure out (

Comment: and key is always string ?

Comment: do you need the value or the reference to the parent object?

Comment: you say you tried stuff - well what was that?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will not write the code for you but give you an idea may be it will help, First convert JSON object in to string using

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

after that search for Key using indexOf() method. 
Extract previous '{' and Next '}' string and again cast in to JSON object.
using

```
var obj =  JSON.parse(string);
```

Then

```
 var value = obj.key
```

Comment: Ended up with: `/(?!^)("key[^\\]+?)(?=,)/g`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think this migth be solution (asuming key is always string and you don't care about res of data)

```js
const data = [`"Records": { 
    "test": {
        "test2": [
            {
                "key": "334",
    "key": "3343"
            }
        ]
    }
}`, `"Records": { 
    "test": {
        "key": "512"
    }
}`, `"Records": {
    "key": "112"
}`]

const getKeys = data => {
  const keys = []
  const regex = /"key"\s*:\s*"(.*)"/g
  let temp
  while(temp = regex.exec(data)){
    keys.push(temp[1])
  }
  return keys
}

for(let json of data){
  console.log(getKeys(json))
}
```

Comment: @ShobhitWalia why you think so ? - it asumes you don't care about rest of data `JSON.parse` also is not instant

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get it?

Recursively! e.g.

```
function getKey(rec) {
    if (rec.key) return rec.key;

    return getKey(rec[Object.keys(rec)[0]]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/su42h2et/

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for getting the object with `key` in it.

```js
function getKeyReference(object) {
    function f(o) {
        if (!o || typeof o !== 'object') {
            return;
        }
        if ('key' in o) {
            reference = o;
            return true;
        }
        Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
            return f(o[k]);
        });
    }

    var reference;
    f(object);
    return reference;
}

var o1 = { Records: { key: "112" } },
    o2 = { Records: { test: { key: "512" } } },
    o3 = { Records: { test: { test2: [{ key: "334" }] } } };

console.log(getKeyReference(o1));
console.log(getKeyReference(o2));
console.log(getKeyReference(o3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
const data = {
 "Records": {
  "key": "112"
 }
};

const data2 = {
 "Records": {
  "test": { "key": "512" }
 }
};

const data3 = {
 "Records": {
  "test": {
   "test2": [
    { "key": "334" },
   ]
  }
 }
};

function searchKey(obj, key = 'key') {
 return Object.keys(obj).reduce((finalObj, objKey) => {
  if (objKey !== key) {
   return searchKey(obj[objKey]);
  } else {
   return finalObj = obj[objKey];
  }

 }, [])
}

const result = searchKey(data);
const result2 = searchKey(data2);
const result3 = searchKey(data3);
console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```