# Parsing JSON to find object by key value

Tags: json, node.js

I am working with a much larger JSON file than I am used too and I am getting confused on how to parse the file to extract an object.

```
resultJSON['BACSDocument']['Data'][0]['ARUDD'][0]['Advice'][0]['OriginatingAccountRecords'][0]['OriginatingAccountRecord'][0]['ReturnedDebitItem']
```

This is what I used to extract the "ReturnedDebitItem" array. I cannot use this as the json will come in different schemas but will always contain a "ReturnedDebitItem" so I need to parse the document.

I have tried using a couple of for loops but I am just receiving errors - any insight would be much appreciated. I am working with node but any pseudo code would also be helpful!

Comment: gonna need to see some code to help with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Find key and its value in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492555/javascript-find-key-and-its-value-in-json)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! What code do you need? I can't show the JSON file online - but basically I have taken an XML file parsed it into JSON and now I need to extract "ReturnedDebitItem" from that JSON and upload it to a database

Comment: @tspoon _"I have tried using a couple of for loops but I am just receiving errors"_ - this code we want to see